# Simple 8086 Assembly String Array and Printing

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I have to write a program for my Assembly class that allows the user to enter his/her full name and the program then utilizes and array to store the characters and print them in the following order: "LastName", "Middle"(Optional and can have more than one middle name" "First".  I have gotten my program to almost do this except it prints out a '$' at the start of the Last name. I have tried incrementing the index (bx) but then it gives me a garbled output. I am fairly new to assembly so please bear with me. I am thinking my macros might be interfering with my output when I increment the index. Also please bear with my formatting. I can never transfer code correctly. Thanks in Advance!

Here is my code:

```
       ;This Program Reads in a user's full name and prints out the results in the format 
        'Lastname', 'Middle'(Optional), First using an array. 

 include pcmac.inc
.MODEL SMALL
    .586  ;Allows Pentium instructions. Must come after .MODEL

    .STACK 100h

    .DATA
 MAXBUF EQU 100
 GetBuf DB MAXBUF
 GetCnt DB ?
 CharStr DB  MAXBUF DUP (?)
 Message DB 'Enter your full name',10,13,'$'
 Message2 DB 'Here is your name in the correct format', 10,13,'$'
 Count DB 0

    .CODE
Array PROC  
    _Begin
    _PutStr Message
    _GetStr GetBuf


mov bl, GetCnt
sub bh,bh

   FindLast:

   cmp [CharStr+bx],32
   je SeperateLast
   dec bx
   inc Count        ;Counter to record how long the lastname is
   jmp FindLast



  SeperateLast:

     mov [CharStr+bx],'$'
    _PutStr Message2
    jmp Printlast



 FirstName:

     _PutCh ',',32              ;Add comma and space for readability
     _PutStr CharStr            ;Print up to the inputted dollar sign
     _PutCh 10,13

     jmp Done


   Printlast:

      cmp Count,0    
      je FirstName
      _PutCh[CharStr+bx]           ;Print Last Name Character by Character
      inc bx
      dec Count
      jmp Printlast

Done:


     _Exit 0
         Array ENDP

              END Array
```

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is this. You seem to be properly find the last name and you replace the space with the $ sign just before the last name (which seems correct). It seems to me that you want to skip over the $ sign by incrementing `BX` by one, and then decrementing the Count by 1. So After `mov [CharStr+bx],'$'` try adding `inc bx` and then `dec Count`

Comment: That did it. I was just incrementing BX and forgetting to decrement Count. Thank you! It's not showing the arrow to mark your answer as the correct one. I will figure it out and get you your rep. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, you seem to be properly finding the last name. Since the space before the last name represents the end of the First and Middle name it makes sense to replace the space with the $ sign just before the last name. Since *BX* is the offset of the dollar sign you just put in, you should increment *BX* by one to skip over it. You then need to decrement the `Count` variable by 1 as well.

This code:

```
mov [CharStr+bx],'$'
_PutStr Message2
jmp Printlast
```

Should probably be something like:

```
mov [CharStr+bx],'$'
inc bx
dec Count
_PutStr Message2
jmp Printlast
```

Comment: The *count* variable is not too high for the reason that you mention. It's overshot by 1 because the *FindLast* loop erroneously starts comparing at the terminating carriage return. (Correct code: `mov bl, GetCnt` `sub bh,bh` `dec bx`)